# setInterval doesn't work correctly in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use `setInterval` function for my website infinite loop, but Firefox only handles the first interval and for next one, the fav icon of my site changes to loading, and F5 and refresh button don't work.

```
function printTime()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + sec);
}

setInterval("printTime()", 1000);
```

Comment: `document.write`? SRSLY?

Comment: `document.write` on a page that's not open for writing will invoke `document.open`, and `document.open` clears the page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's totally expected. Don't use `document.write` [apart during the initial loading of the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write#Notes).

Create an element and append it to the body instead.

For example :

```
function printTime(){
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    var txt = document.createTextNode(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + sec);
    document.body.appendChild(txt); 
}
setInterval(printTime, 1000); // note also the difference here : don't eval
```

Note that after a few hours, your page will be a little long. If you wanted to change an element instead of appending, you'd do

```
document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + sec;
```

Comment: I've read the website of the URL you've posted. There is one thing I don't get: Why does following code not work. First I insert a `document.open()`, after that do the `document.write()` and finally do a `document.close()`?

Comment: This stops the page and the script. Obviously this can't work with `setInterval`. Just remember : *Never try to use document.write after the initial page load*. Using `document.write` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I don't use it anyway, but was curious about the explanation why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `document.write`. try something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function printTime() {
        var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.getHours();
        var mins = now.getMinutes();
        var sec = now.getSeconds();
        $("#myDiv").html(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + sec);
    }

    setInterval(printTime, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test">Hello</div>
```

add above html in your document and run this script

```
var flag = false;
function printTime()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
//    document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + sec);
 if(flag==true)
 {
    document.getElementById("test").backgroundColor="green";
    flag = false;
 }else
 {
    document.getElementById("test").backgroundColor="red";
    flag = true;
 }

}

setInterval("printTime()", 1000);
```

if it doesn't work then balim Firefox :) although it will work surely

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple example:**

```
function printTime()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    var div = document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + sec;

}

setInterval(printTime(), 1000);
```